# Need help to sync object with Briefcase SyncDown target which are shared by backend later

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

Briefcase sync down target is not able to sync object whose access is granted by salesforce backend much later after their creation.

I am facing issue in below scenario, Account related to ServiceAppointment are shared to ServiceResource by our Salesforce App based on some rules. in this process LastModifiedDate of Account is not changed when it is shared so Briefcase priming api is not able to return the record if some other Account with LastModifiedDate is greater is already synced.

Please suggest workaround for this